# How to remove duplicates from different columns table in sql

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have data in which i have duplicates but in different columns for ex :

| Column A | Column B |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 |
| 2 | 1 |
| 3 | 4 |
| 4 | 3 |

but now my output should look like

| Column A | Column B |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 |
| 3 | 4 |

how can i achieve this using sql query ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We can use a least/greatest trick here:

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT LEAST(a, b) AS a, GREATEST(a, b) AS b
FROM yourTable;
```

The idea is to, e.g., take the two tuples `(1, 2)` and `(2, 1)` and bring them both to `(1, 2)`, using the `LEAST()` and `GREATEST()` functions.  Then, we just retain one them using `DISTINCT`.